# $\sin(n^a)$ dense in $[-1,1]$, $a>1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a>1$, then the sequence $u_n=\sin(n^a)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Let $b=E[a]+1$ and $x\in[0,2\pi[$. For $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $p_n\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$(p_n+1)^a> x_n-x > p_n^a\quad\mbox{ where }x_n=2(E[x]+1)(n+1)^b\pi$$
Our gaol is to prove there exists a subsequence of $(p_n^a-x_n)_n$ converging to $-x$. We have
$$(p_n+1)^a-x_n > -x > p_n^a-x_n,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N $$
Then,
$$ L=\liminf((p_n+1)^a-x_n) \mbox{ exists and  }L\geq -x.$$
There exists $\phi :\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\uparrow$:
$$L=\lim((p_{\phi(n)}+1)^a-x_{\phi(n)}) .$$
The some, $$ \ell=\limsup(p_{\phi(n)}^a-x_{\phi(n)}) \mbox{  exists and 
 }\ell\leq -x.$$
There exists $\psi :\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\uparrow$ :
$$\ell= \lim (p_{\phi(\psi(n))}^a-x_{\phi(\psi(n))}) \leq -x.$$
We also have,
$$L=\lim((p_{\phi(\psi(n))}+1)^a-x_{\phi(\psi(n))}) \geq -x.$$
Then, $$\lim((p_{\phi(\psi(n))}+1)^a-p_{\phi(\psi(n))}^a)=L-\ell,
$$ so,  $\lim a p_{\phi(\psi(n))}^{a-1}=L-\ell$ ?
This is absurd? Surprising result where is the error?
Tanks.

Comment: Please edit typos and improve clarity

Comment: It can be proved that $\{n^q/{2\pi}\}$ is equidistributed on $[0,1)$ for $q>0$.